# Can an application be notified when another app writes to an sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite

I have two linux apps.

One app writes data to an sqlite3 database at fairly random intervals.

The other app must process the data that's been added.

Is there any feature of sqlite3 that facilitates the second app being notified when the first app has written to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want a [data change notification callback](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a file-system listener and take this out of SQLite's hands.